# How to preserve the order of points extracted from a polygon

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

[image]

When use this query to get the points of the polygon, I don't get them in the proper order.

```
select num_bornes,x,y 
from point 
where geom in (select (st_dumppoints(geom)).geom 
               from polygon 
               where id_polygon=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`St_dumppoints` also returns the polygon ring and point ID, so you would fetch and order by this ID. You can also use a `join`, instead of an `in` clause, to return all point from the polygons, which will allow you to spot missing points in your point layer.

```
SELECT num_bornes,x,y,  dptable.pointID
FROM point 
RIGHT JOIN  
    (SELECT (dp).path[1] As ringID,
        (dp).path[2] As pointID,
        (dp).geom ptgeom
    FROM (SELECT st_dumppoints(geom) dp
          FROM polygon 
    WHERE id_polygon=1 ) a) dptable
ON  ST_Equals(point.geom, dptable.ptgeom)
ORDER BY dptable.pointID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like they are in order in the picture. What if you simply use order by like

```
    select num_bornes,x,y 
from point 
where geom in (select (st_dumppoints(geom)).geom 
               from polygon 
               where id_polygon=1) order by num_bornes
```